# Redirect WP 404 to html

Tags: html, 404-error

Needing to redirect php 404 to plain html to reduce server load.

Is there any update to this? [How do I skip wordpress's 404 handling and redirect all 404 errors for static files to 404.html?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24587/how-do-i-skip-wordpresss-404-handling-and-redirect-all-404-errors-for-static-fi)

```
#adding your own handler
ErrorDocument 404 /404/index.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(404|cgi-bin|wp-admin|wp-content|wp-includes)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have it:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://domain.com/custom_404.php
```

You just have to create the static 404 page called `custom_404.php` in your child theme or the root of your domain. Child theme would be:

```
http://domain.com/wp-content/themes/child_theme/custom_404.php
```